Problem with 2D projection
I have a green circle:

Inside the circle, the white frame moves to wherever P, the projection of the targets 3D position into a 2D point,  is.
However, outside the circle, the frame will move to the direction the target is, but will stop at the radius of the circle and cannot get out. I did this with this pseudo code:
if frameisoutofcircle then
frameposition = centerposition + targetdirection (unit vector) * radius
the only problem is, when I'm facing away from the target, this sort of thing happens:

practically, the target projected point facing away from the target is within the circle, even though the target is behind! Heres another image to understand better:

The rectangle with the circle is the player camera with the circle in image one
What I want is the frame to be on the border of the circle pointing towards the target even if the players back is turned away from the target. Ive seen something about projecting 3D lines (line between target and camera) onto the 2D player camera plane, but I don't know if that's a good idea?
EDIT:
I guess my question is kind of how do I get the line between the target and the player, and then project that so it returns as a line from the center of the circle in image one of that circle. Please write for further clarification.

I didn't know if to put this in stack exchange or here, so someone please tell me if this is the wrong site.

The question doesn't seem to be off-topic here & in my opinion, this is probably a better fit than SO. You state that white frame moves to wherever target position P is, but how exactly is the frame situated relative to that point? For example, is P the center of the frame, the upper right corner, etc?

Practically, P is the projected point of the 3D point of the target onto the camera, and the frame tries to be at the 2D point P as long as its within the circle.

Use the 3D dot product of the player and target as a component of the calculations, the sign alone will indicate in front of or behind.
If you want the player to face the target to get the target within the circle: If the dot product is negative, then rotate the player 180 degrees and recalculate.

Hi there! Unfortunately this wasnt what I was looking for, but Ive managed to resolve my issue! Thanks again!
